# How to duplicate multiple work items at once in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

We use Azure DevOps to plan our sprints using the Scrum template.
The sprints usually contain recurring PBIs (product backlog items), e.g. "customer support", "pull requests reviews", etc.

Creating these recurring PBIs and the related tasks for each sprint is a tedious work and the DevOps-function to copy one single PBI doesn't make it much faster.

Is there any possibility to copy multiple PBIs (including their child tasks) from one sprint to another at once?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/copy-clone-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser Scrumming is so 1995

Comment: @Gantendo I read that page, but as much as I understood the "copy to clipboard" function only allows to copy the PBIs as HTML to an e-mail client.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64549289/how-can-we-copy-a-bulk-of-workitems-from-one-project-to-another-in-azure-devops

Comment: @Gantendo I'm not sure if this works for my case because I don't need to copy work items from Project A to Project B, but From Sprint N to Sprint N+1 of the same project.

Comment: Dario, not sure if I understand correctly, but why duplicate them in the first place? Why not just assign them to the next sprint?

Comment: @Jacques because the PBIs i mentioned are recurring ones, e.g. we have a timeboxed PBI for the customer support during each sprint.

Comment: @Dario Ah, I've recently run into the same issue with deployments. We have very specific deployment procedures so we need those recurring items and they can't be moved from sprint to sprint. I haven't found a solution to this yet, but will share if I find something.

Comment: I know this is ancient news now but [Work Item Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/work-item-template?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) might be a partial solution for this kind of problem.